# Redirect pages in a subfolder to a new page in same subfolder htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect several pages to a new page, the easiest way to explain is this...

http://www.example.com/numbers/0800/bronze.html TO http://www.example.com/numbers/0800/bronze-new.html

http://www.example.com/numbers/0845/bronze.html TO http://www.example.com/numbers/0800/bronze-new.html

Any ideas how to do this in one htaccess rule? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-new\.html$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(numbers/.+?)\.html$ /$1-new.html [L,R,NC]
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the suggestion, it nearly works, but it makes the link like this https://www.example.com/numbers/0800/bronze-new-new-new-new-new-new-new-new-new-new-new-new-new-new-new-new-new-new-new-new.html